# Display Json object in HTML unordered list using Razor

Tags: jquery, json, razor, model-view-controller

I am using my Controller to return a Json object to my script in my View. I am then using jquery to build my HTML elements which consists of a checkbox and some values from the Json object. 
I feel that Razor will be more efficient than how I'm displaying these elements now. It will alsoAnd will also make it easier for me when I create functions based the checkbox input.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction of how to create an razor elements for checkbox and labels contained in an unordered list.

My Controller:

```
[Authorize]
    public JsonResult GetSnackTypes()
    {
        List<SnackVM> snacks = new List<SnackVM>();
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.Snacks = GetSnackTypes().Select(a => new SnackVM
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Name = a.Name,
            ExtraID = a.ExtraID,
            BaseCost = a.BaseCost
        }).ToList();
        snacks = vm.Snacks;
        return Json(snacks);
    }
```

Script:

```
GetSnackTypes = function () {
        var snackResults = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetSnackTypes", "Wizard")",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
        }).done(function (result) {
            snackResults = result;
        });

        return snackResults
    }
```

I then call this function and build my HTML elements in another function. If the month option is selected I need to multiply my value.BaseCost by 4:

```
        var snackResults = [];
        snackResults = GetSnackTypes();

        var html = '<ul>';
        $.each(snackResults, function (key, value) {
            if (foodPlan == "MONTH")
                html += '<li><input type="checkbox" id=' + value.Id + '><label>' + value.Name + ' $' + value.BaseCost * 4 + ".00" + '</label></li>';
            else
                html += '<li><input type="checkbox" id=' + value.Id + '><label>' + value.Name + ' $' + value.BaseCost + ".00" + '</label></li>';
        });
        html += '<li><input type="checkbox"><label>' + 'I do not want snacks! ' + '</label></li>';
        html += '</ul>';

        var snackSection = $('#snackSection');

        snackSection.html(html);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="snackSection">

</div>
```

It displays correct at the moment but I think using Razor will help me in the long run. 
I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Is this question about the Razor view engine for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: It is yes. I was thinking Razor would offer me a more efficient and neater solution to my problem. Building the HTML elements in the Javascript works but I have a feeling it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetSnackTypes` method could return a partial view with all the html instead of Json.

Partial view `_Snacks.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<SnackVM>

<ul>
    @foreach (var snack in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id=' + value.Id + '><label>@string.Format("{0} ${1:n2}", snack.Name, snack.BaseCost * (ViewBag.FoodPlan == "MONTH" ? 4 : 1))</label>
        </li>
    }
    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>I do not want snacks!</label></li>
</ul>
```

Controller action:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetSnackTypes(string foodPlan)
    {
        var snacks = GetSnackTypes().Select(a => new SnackVM
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Name = a.Name,
            ExtraID = a.ExtraID,
            BaseCost = a.BaseCost
        }).ToList();
        ViewBag.FoodPlan = foodPlan;
        return PartialView("_Snacks", snacks);
    }
```

Javascript 1:

```
GetSnackTypes = function () {
        var snackResults = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetSnackTypes", "Wizard")",
            data: { foodPlan: "MONTH" },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            type: "POST"
        }).done(function (result) {
            snackResults = result;
        });

        return snackResults
    }
```

Javascript 2:

```
var snackResults = [];
snackResults = GetSnackTypes();
var html = $(snackResults);
var snackSection = $('#snackSection');
snackSection.html(html);
```